# How to stop Dreamweaver from loading attached scripts and CSS files on opening an HTML file?

Tags: dreamweaver

Dreamweaver takes too long to load when opening a file.

HTML files have more than 20 - 25 JS and 10-15 CSS file attached on them and it makes Dreamweaver lag.

How do I stop Dreamweaver from loading attached scripts and CSS files?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Dreamweaver goto Edit > preferences > general > under document options uncheck option "Enable Related Files"